# Fire button click When OnTextChanged occur inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, repeater, textchanged

need help on this (simplyfied) situation:
I nave a repeater with a textbox and a button.

How can i fire button click when the text is changed?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_itemCommand" >                    
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:textbox ID="txt" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtChg" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" CommandName="btn" CommandArgument="myVal" runat="server" Text="Confirm" /></td>                          
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

'code behind:

```
Protected Sub txtChg(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim txt As TextBox = (sender)
        dim txtStr as string = txt.text 
    'more code....
     Catch ex As Exception
        'ex.message
     End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub rpt_itemCommand(s As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "btn" Then
        'more code...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what is going wrong with it now exactly? The event should fire next time your page is posted back, if (and only if) the values in the textbox have changed since the last time the page was loaded.

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply.

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply. I need to fire the button click when text is changed (both button and textbox are inside a repeater), so the button click is handled in sub rpt_itemCommand and text change is handled in sub txtChg. I suppose that i need to reference the button in  sub txtChg but can't get it working. Thanks Again for supporting.

Comment: "I need to fire the button click" ...are you really wanting to do this on the client side using JavaScript? Otherwise I'm not sure how it would make any sense to fire a button click event from the server.

Comment: I wonder if part of the issue here is that a Repeater creates its elements dynamically (depending on the number of items in the data source) - so perhaps it therefore cannot preserve the state of the textbox from one postback to another, because it doesn't know if the textbox actually relates to the same record or not. That would be my guess. It's years since I worked on WebForms (MVC is **much** easier to use!) but I recall issues with viewstate relating to things like repeaters and gridviews whose elements are bound to dynamic data sources.

Comment: I'll try to explain:
I have a repeater with a textbox and a button. 

The button has the database rowID as commandArgument (it could also be a hidden field...).
The textbox has the new text

What i need is update the database specific row with the new text.

So how can i access the button properties from within textchanged event?

Many Thanks Again.

Comment: I don't think you can. The textchanged event only knows about the textbox itself. It has no context about what is near the textbox, or that it was part of the repeater. But if you just want to update the specific row after the button is pressed then you don't need the textchanged event for that, instead handle the correct command event of the repeater. From memory I think it's ItemCommand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand?view=netframework-4.8 . You can do the database update from there.

Comment: P.s. It doesn't make much sense to say you want to fire the button click event from the text changed event. In that scenario, how did a postback occur in the first place (in order for the text changed event to fire)? Some other button click or what? I'm not understanding how that situation would occur. Like I said much earlier, if you want to trigger a button click based on the text having changed, you'd be better of doing that in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for reply, as said in main post, that was a simplyfied situation. I actually don't want to "click" the button, just want to know how access button properties (or hiddenfield as well) in order to get rowID value. I know this could be done via repeater namingcontainer methods/properties but can't figure out how.

Comment: you'd have to find the correct row in the repeater. But I don't know how you'd do that, because the textchanged event doesn't carry any information which would tell you the row to find. Again, how are you firing the postback which is causing the textchanged event? Is there some button being clicked on?

Comment: Dim itm As RepeaterItem = CType(CType(sender, Control).NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)
        Dim rowID As Integer = CType(itm.FindControl("hfPostItID"), HiddenField).Value

Comment: Using the above code i can get repeater's items from within textcanged event but it return only the first ID (value of hiddenfiel control in repeater)